# MKNetworkKit - Host Name and apiPath parameters

Tags: ios, mknetworkkit

I was thinking of using MKNetworkKit as base for Network operations for an iOS App. I'm a bit confused about using the initWithHostName:customerHeaders: and initWithHostName: apiPath:customerHeaders: methods.

In the App, I need to communicate to a number of hosts and they have different ways of specifying the Host Name and URL. For example:

HostNameX.com - The Domain Name for HostX,

The first host has the service prepended to the Hostname as so:

serviceA.HostNameX.com?someparam=value  The Path for ServiceA (returns info)
serviceB.HostNameX.com?someparam=value  The Path for ServiceB (returns info)

---

HostNameY.com - The Domain Name for HostY

The second host has the service or command appended to the Hostname as so:

HostNameY.com/serviceA?someparam =value  The Path for ServiceA (returns info)
HostNameY.com/serviceB?someparam =value  The Path for ServiceB (returns info)

---

For the HostNameY.com case, I was thinking of creating one MKEngine Instance and then passing in the "serviceA?someparam=value" or "serviceB?someparam=value" string as the Path parameter to the operationWithPath:params:httpMethod:ssl: method.

This would work well for what I want to do, however for HostNameX.com I'm not sure how to prepend "serviceA." or "serviceB." to the host name? The only way I can see of doing it is to create two separate MKEngine Instances one for "serviceA" and one for "serviceB". Is this the case?

Am I missing something or is there a way to be able to prepend the service to the domain name after calling initWithHostName:apiPath:customerHeaders: ?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.
All the Best
Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using the operationWithURLString and building my own URL String. To me anyway, this seems a much better solution than allocating a number of MKEngine Instances just to handle something that can be passed as a parameter. This way I can also append path components as well as parameters to the URL String, for example:

http://serviceA.hostname.com/fred/simmons?isvip=true&hasBooked=false

Interestingly, the parameter dictionary that is passed to operationWithURLString:params:httpMethod: works in two ways:

if the httpMethod is GET, then the dictionary is used to pass parameters in the URL, if the httpMethod is POST or PUT (or DELETE?) then the Dictionary is formatted and sent as the Request Body.

Question - is it valid to have a POST Command with parameters?

For example:

http://bookingservice.hostname.com/bookings?isvip=true&lastname=simmons

Is this a valid URL as a POST not a GET?

Answer (score 0):

For HostNameY.com, you are right. The service name can be part of the path.

And as you mentioned, you should use multiple instances of MKEngine to manage HostNameX.com.

Why you should use multiple instances :
Hostname is a private property of MKNetworkEngine and the only way to change the hostname is to create a new instance of MKNetworkEngine (without modifying MKNetworkEngine). Hostname property is used by MKNetworkEngine to observe Reachability changes and freeze/restore operations. If you change the hostname at runtime for a single instance of MKNetworkEngine (by making hostname property public for example), this feature won't work well on all situations. Just take a look at freezeOperations (called when you loose network) method in MKNetworkEngine.m. It checks if and operation url contains the current hostname. If you have changed the hostname and the operation was created for another host, the operation will not be archived to restore it later when the network is back.

Comment: So that would imply that there are two host names, serviceA.HostNameX and serviceB.HostNameX, rather then one? Also, there is no way to prepend the "serviceXXX." to the host name, once the MKEngine Subclass has been Allocated/Inited?

Comment: At the moment, I'm counting 27 separate "Services" for HostNameX and I think there will be more. So, I'd have to create and maintain 27 NKEngine Instances, seems VERY inefficient as apposed to just having one instance and prepending the service name to it. If this is true I'm thinking it might not be a good idea to use MKNetworkKit after all?

Comment: I've been digging into the code of MKNetworkKit and HostName is separate from the path. I'm going to investigate changing it to add a other property to Prepend when building the final URL String.

Comment: Had another idea, pass nil as HostName to  MKNetworkKitinitWithHostName:customerHeaders: or initWithHostName: apiPath:customerHeaders and then use operationWithURL instead of OperationWithPath - Obviously I have to build my own URL string, but this seems better than having a lot of instances of MKEngine Subclass?

Comment: Managing so much instances are obviously not very elegant/efficient. But the services you want to use are not exposed in a very standard way. If you go with operationWithURLString, you loose reachability, freezing/restoring features of this framework. You will need to manage network problems by your own. On the other side if you go with operationWithURLString, you won't play with multiple instances. As always, Pros and cons on each side